# SwiftUI View Sizing (Parent/Child Relationship)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm working though some examples to get familiar with SwiftUI and I am having an issue with sizing.

I'm used to the way UIKit handles resizing views, where with AutoLayout you can essentially make a parent size to it's children. This does not seem to be the case with SwiftUI.

Everything that I've read has shown how to use GeometryReader on the child to get the size of its parent is suggesting, and that the child can then choose it's own size, but I have not seen how to get the child's size from the parent.

Say I have the following code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is Text").ripple(rippleColor: .lightGray, rippleOpacity: 0.5)
    }
}
```

`ripple()` is an extension function that adds a custom `ViewModifier` that overlays the content onto a `UIViewRepresentable` view for the purposes of creating a material ripple effect when tapping.

```swift
struct RippleModifier: ViewModifier {
    let rippleColor: UIColor
    let rippleOpacity: Float

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        RippleView(
            rippleColor: rippleColor,
            rippleOpacity: rippleOpacity
        )
        .overlay(content)
    }
}

extension View {
    func ripple(rippleColor: UIColor, rippleOpacity: Float) -> some View {
        modifier(
            RippleModifier(
                rippleColor: rippleColor,
                rippleOpacity: rippleOpacity
            )
        )
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when I just have the `Text`, it sets its frame to fit its content (the string). When I add the `.ripple()` modifier to it, the frame then becomes the entire screen.

With UIKit, I'd just add some constraints to pin what would be the UILabel to the parent, and I'd let that dictate the size of the parent.

Is there a way to do with with SwiftUI?

Bonus question:

Related but unrelated, how do I get the taps on the `Text` to fall through to the view it's overlaid on? The ripple will activate and properly animate when tapping anywhere within the frame of the view with the exception of tapping directly on the text itself.

### Edit:

Here is partial code for the UIViewRepresentable view.

```swift
struct RippleView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var rippleColor: UIColor = .systemGray
    var rippleOpacity: Float = 0.5

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIRippleView {
        UIRippleView()
    }

    func updateUIView(
        _ uiView: UIRippleView,
        context: UIViewRepresentableContext<RippleView>
    ) {
        uiView.rippleColor = rippleColor
        uiView.rippleOpacity = rippleOpacity
    }
}

open class UIRippleView: UIView {
    open var rippleColor: UIColor = .systemGray {
        didSet {
            rippleLayer.fillColor = rippleColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    open var rippleOpacity: Float = 0.5 {
        didSet {
            rippleLayer.opacity = rippleOpacity
        }
    }

    private lazy var rippleLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.opacity = 0.0

        self.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)

        return layer
    }()

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        clipsToBounds = true
    }

    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

There's an extension to that view that overrides the touch functions to calculate where the tap happened and to perform the animations, but that just modifies the `path` of the `rippleLayer`.

Comment: Can you also show the code of `Ripple`. Or just the minimal example of the full working code?

Comment: Added the additional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `overlay` to `background` like this:

```
struct RippleModifier: ViewModifier {
    let rippleColor: UIColor
    let rippleOpacity: Float

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.background(
            RippleView(
                rippleColor: rippleColor,
                rippleOpacity: rippleOpacity
        ))
    }
}
```

So the `RippleView` gets the size constraint from the `content` and not the other way around.

Comment: This does in fact work, but now I'm having the issue I described in the Bonus Question in my original question. Is there a way to make the `Text` not steal the touches from the UIView?

Comment: This is technically the correct the answer, so I will mark it as such.

Comment: I actually seemed to have solved my own issue. For some reason, by adding a `.clipped()` to the `content` after setting the `background`, it now recognizes touches